# Scala: Does reduceLeft and reduceRight have accumulator at different positions?

Tags: scala

I am a littlebit confused between the methods reduceleft and reduceRight in Scala. Here's a Snippet that I am testing:

```
val intList = List(5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
    println(intList.reduceRight((curr, acc) => { //Reduce right me y is accumulator
        println(s"First  Curr = $curr, Acc = $acc")
        curr - acc
    }));
    println(intList.reduceLeft((curr, acc) => { // List(1,2,3,4,5) // Accumulator is the first Element
    println(s"Second Curr = $curr, Acc = $acc")
    acc - curr}))
```

And the Output is as shown below:

```
First  Curr = 2, Acc = 1
First  Curr = 3, Acc = 1
First  Curr = 4, Acc = 2
First  Curr = 5, Acc = 2
3
Second Curr = 5, Acc = 4
Second Curr = -1, Acc = 3
Second Curr = 4, Acc = 2
Second Curr = -2, Acc = 1
```

In both the iterations what I observe is that in case of reduceRight we have (`curr`,`acc`) [Meaning curr is passed as first argument and accumulator as second], whereas in case of `reduceLeft` we have (`acc`,`curr`).

Is there any specific reason behind this inconsistency in the arguments?

Comment: Is the same as `foldLeft` & `foldRight` where the types are different and are just to remember you the order of the associativity of the operation.{

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use a little visualization:

`reduceLeft`:

```
                 a  b c d e
  acc1 = f(a, b)  \/ / / /
acc2 = f(acc1, c)  \/ / /
 acc3 = f(acc2, d)  \/ /
  acc4 = f(acc3, e)  \/
```

`reduceRight`:

```
a b c d  e
 \ \ \ \/  acc1 = f(d, e)
  \ \ \/  acc2 = f(c, acc1)
   \ \/  acc3 = f(b, acc2)
    \/  acc4 = f(a, acc3)
```

The order of arguments help us remember the where the arguments came from and in which order they were evaluated. Because this is quite important to not confuse left-associative and right-associative operations:

- any visual help matters and writing `acc` on the correct side of function makes reasoning easier
- lambdas in `coll.reduceLeft(_ operation _)` and `coll.reduceRight(_ operation _)` would have *very* confusing behavior if `acc` were on left in both cases

Imagine if you defined a right-associative operator e.g. `a ** b` (a to the power of b). Exponentiation in math is right-associative, so `a ** b ** c` should behave like `a ** (b ** c)`. Someone decides to calculate such use case using `rightReduce`, because it implements exactly this behavior. They do

```
List(a, b, c).reduceRight(_ ** _)
```

and then they learn that someone decided that `acc` should be on left side because they wanted it to be "consistent" with `reduceLeft`. **That** would be much more inconsistent with every intuitions that you carried from mathematics.